# How to make form submit with post in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am learning laravel 5.4 framework.

**In web.php:**

```
Route::post('form-submit',[

'uses' => 'Admincontroller@formSubmit',
'as' => 'f.submit',

]);
```

**Admincontroller is:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Customer;

class Admincontroller extends controller{

public function index()
{
//echo"Index method";
return view('Welcome');
}
public function formSubmit()
{
    echo"HTML form submit";
} 
?>
```

**xyz.blade.php is:**

```
@extends('layout/test-data2')
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'form-submit'])  !!}
{!! Form::text('field_one') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('submit') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

After run form-submit, a form should be open and if click on button then message "HTML form submit" should be echo.

But when I run link, then post is not working and give error:

```
When I run url admin3, then got error:

(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php line 251
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php line 238
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php line 176
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php line 546
```

But when I use get it shows only text message: **HTML form submit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntex is correct, there is nothing wrong, Thing is that you can not simply run a POST url, that will be consider as GET request.

For  POST to work you need to specify that its a post request.Like in the form we specify that

```
<form method="post" action=<URL HERE>> </form>
```

You see we mention that its a post request. 
But if you simply try to access `www.example.com/admin3` that will be consider as GET request as a result of which you are getting that error.

And one more thing,
For post request in the controller, add `Request $request` to capture the post data. Something like this

```
public function postindex(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->all(); //This will give you the data of all post value
    echo"Index method";
    //return view('Welcome');
}
```

Dont forget to import the  Request as well.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. But in my example there is no any form

Comment: Then do not use POST, that will not work. unless you specify in the header that it is a post request

Comment: Please wait for two mins. I will ask a new question and will paste link here

Comment: Try changing this  `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'form-submit', 'method' => 'post'])  !!}` see wt happens. and add that Request $request toy ur post controler

Comment: Can we please connect with teamviewer or anydesk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173266/discussion-between-user7747472-and-cloud-soft).